# Laravel - trying to Delete the Old records before insert New records

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to delete the old records before inserting new ones using Laravel.

First I tried using `delete()` , then found the `404 not found` error because I'm using a Controller.

Changed to `destroy()` and now I'm facing the `BadMethodCallException` error

> BadMethodCallException
> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::destroy()

My code:

```
MyClass::where('field_id', $id)->destroy();
```

I'm stuck, dunno how to do it properly. The idea it's to remove the old records and insert the new ones after it.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the 404 error you can try this:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $data = Model::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
    
    $data->delete();
    
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Record has been deleted permanently..!');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting your controller method to something like this:

```php
/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    MyClass::where('field_id', $id)->delete();

    return response()->json(['success' => true]);
}
```

Comment: Included this command inside the controller and got the same "404 not found" error.

Comment: Try running a test command from `php artisan tinker`, also could you share the relevant section of your routes file?

Answer (score -1):

if you want to avoid the 404 error you can do something like this:

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $data = MyModel::where('field', $id)->get();

    if(count($data)){ 

      $data->delete();

    }

    return response()->json(['success' => true]);
}
```